# Two algorithms side by side and synchronized

Tags: formatting, algorithm2e

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            algo1-line1\\
            algo1-still line 1 but in the next line\\
            algo1-line2\\
            algo1-line 3
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            algo2-line1\\
            algo2-line2\\
            algo2-still line 2 but in the next line\\
            algo2-line 3
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I wand to aim at is to have both algorithms side by side and to have the lines "synchronized", i.e. the following would be my desired output:

```
(1) algo1-line1                                        algo2-line1
    algo1-still line 1 but in the next line
(2) algo1-line2                                        algo2-line2
                                                       algo2-still line 2 but in the next line
(3) algo1-line 3                                       algo2-line 3
```

Would someone be so kind to help me with that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can make the width smaller

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            algo1-line1\\
            algo1-still line 1 but in the next line\\
            algo1-line2\\
            algo1-line 3
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            algo2-line1\\
            algo2-line2\\
            algo2-still line 2 but in the next line\\
            algo2-line 3
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not yield a line numbering as I would like to have it. Do you have any idea how to achieve that?